# Native image construction of a Quarkus application breaks when referencing Geotools library

Tags: quarkus, geotools, graalvm-native-image

The generation of the native image with GraalVM of my application in Quarkus breaks when I'm using the geotools library

I need to find a workarround because I use geotools to read shapefile (SHP format) and convert it to WKT format.

Does anyone know of an alternative to solve this?

I reference these classes in my code:

```
import org.geotools.data.DataStore;
import org.geotools.data.DataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.FeatureSource;
import org.geotools.feature.FeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.feature.FeatureIterator;
```

Comment: what breaks exactly? Is there an error message?

Comment: It starts with "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.media.jai.JAI"

But after thar others  NoClassDefFoundError appear
The problem is Quarkus cannot compile natively if there are handcrafted Singletons like 
public class MyClass {
    public static final INSTANCE = new MyClass()
...
}

Comment: I guess I will give up Geotools... but first I need to find another library that reads shapefiles

Comment: I've no idea what Quarkus is, but that sounds like a bug at their end to me

Comment: Quarkus is a modern java framework, developed by RedHat and taylored to be a container-first solution. You cab know more in https://quarkus.io/